# ModuleNotFoundError: Import class from other file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation
```

I saved this code and then I opened a new file and typed this code

```
from student import student

student1 = student('jake','business',3.1,False)

print(student1.name)
```

I got this error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'student'

I coped pip path and paste it in command prompt then I add to the path  \pip install student

I got this error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement student (from
>   versions: none)

NO matching distribution found for student

ps: I'm using python IDLE

Comment: *"I saved this code"*; what is the name of the file that you saved? *"then I opened a new file"*: is this file in the same directory as the first file?

Comment: "I saved this code" the file's name is classes.And yes both are in the same folder

Comment: If the name of the first file is classes.py, then `from classes import student` should work. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Comment: @Tote99 Update your question with the file names mentioned.

Comment: I tried " from classes import student" and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just make a empty new file `__init__.py` in the same folder.

Comment: I tried yours and I got this      ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

Keep the class implementation in `students.py`and then in other file say(file1.py) import the `student` class:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, Just follow the following step and your problem would get resolved hopefully.
Keep the name of the Class.py file the same in the Object.py file i.e.
If the name of your class file is "Student.py" then you shall write in the object.py file as "from Student import Student"[See the highlighted region in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHrp2.jpg)